# Make scrollbar to be fixed instead of crushing layout

Tags: css

When using layout like this:

```css
div {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 150vh;
  float: left;
  background: rgb(30,120,210)
}
div:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: rgb(210,120,30)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Scrollbar crushes design. Without scrollbar it works just fine, each element takes 1/4 of the screen width. Well one solution would be to add `width: calc(25vw - 17px)` to last element but my grid is way more complicated than that. So I was thinking  if it's possible to make slider have rule similar to `position: fixed` so it goes above elements rather than crushing them. Or even better, if possible, to remove scrollbar. This problem doesn't appear on Linux Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I have no such problem using Google Chrome on OSX. You might want to test you markup on multiple browsers/os first. Don't take the path of bad design just because IE is unable to interpreter HTML.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov OS X and some Linux window managers have layout-free scrollbars by default, they simply overlap the content. Check out System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars: Always

Comment: @IvanVenediktov Yeah I forgot to mention that. On Linux (Ubuntu) Firefox  & Chrome this problem doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `width: 25%` instead of `width: 25vw`? Then the scrollbar will be taken into account.

## Working example:

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 150vh;
  float: left;
  background: rgb(30,120,210)
}
div:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: rgb(210,120,30)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for slow response, took me a while to test this actually (http://i.imgur.com/2P00y5p.png) and it works. A very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `flexbox` it can be simply solved by `flex` and `min-width` properties:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  height: 150vh;
  background: #123;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

So, `max-width` can be used for any new element in the row to follow the rule.

PS: for cross-browser testing, don't forget to [prefix](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) flex properties.

Comment: Sorry it's still too soon to use flex due to older browser support

Comment: Yes, but if you really care about old browsers. But all current browsers support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex. Also you can find polyfills to just support future proof code. I already use it in my projects.

Comment: Thanks for info. I will tend to use flex in my upcoming projects then.